# Issue with quicksight data set unable to import data from data source and also ingestion problem dataset is created using createDataSet api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, amazon-quicksight

```
ArrayList<ResourcePermission> permissions=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> action= new ArrayList<>();
    action.add("quicksight:UpdateDataSourcePermissions");
    action.add("quicksight:DescribeDataSource");
    action.add("quicksight:DescribeDataSourcePermissions");
    action.add("quicksight:PassDataSource");
    action.add("quicksight:UpdateDataSource");
    action.add("quicksight:DeleteDataSource");
    permissions.add(new ResourcePermission().withPrincipal(PrincipalArn).withActions(action));
    return(getClient().createDataSource(new CreateDataSourceRequest().withDataSourceId(DataSourceId).withAwsAccountId(AwsAccountID).withName(DataSourceName).withType(DataSourceType.S3)
            .withDataSourceParameters(new DataSourceParameters().withS3Parameters(new S3Parameters().withManifestFileLocation(new ManifestFileLocation().withBucket(Bucket_Name).withKey(ManifestFileName)))).withPermissions(permissions)));
```

This is code which I am using for creating a dataSource in quicksight

```
Map<String, PhysicalTable> physicalTableMap=new HashMap<String, PhysicalTable>();
    ArrayList<InputColumn> collection =new ArrayList<>();
    PhysicalTable physicalTable=new PhysicalTable().withS3Source(new S3Source().withDataSourceArn(DataSourceArn).withInputColumns(collection).withUploadSettings(new UploadSettings().withContainsHeader(false)));
    physicalTableMap.put("string",physicalTable);
    ArrayList<ResourcePermission> permissions=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> action=new ArrayList<>();
    action.add("quicksight:UpdateDataSetPermissions");
    action.add("quicksight:DescribeDataSet");
    action.add("quicksight:DescribeDataSetPermissions");
    action.add("quicksight:PassDataSet");
    action.add("quicksight:DescribeIngestion");
    action.add("quicksight:ListIngestions");
    action.add("quicksight:UpdateDataSet");
    action.add("quicksight:DeleteDataSet");
    action.add("quicksight:CreateIngestion");
    action.add("quicksight:CancelIngestion");
    permissions.add(new ResourcePermission().withPrincipal(PrincipalArn).withActions(action));
    return(getClient().createDataSet(new CreateDataSetRequest().withAwsAccountId(AwsAccountID).withDataSetId(DataSetId).withName(DataSetName).withPhysicalTableMap(physicalTableMap).withImportMode(DataSetImportMode.SPICE).withPermissions(permissions)));
```

this is code for creating data set in QuickSight
when I use both of this API simultaneously then problem is created data set is not able to import data from dataset or import always failed

also

do i have to use createIngestion API after creating dataset? if yes then how should i use?

Comment: I've never used the QuickSight API, but what do you mean by "when I use both of this API simultaneously"? Are you saying that the problem only occurs if you run the two `createDataSet()` commands _at the same time_? Does it work if you run them separately?

Comment: no i mean when i run `createDataSource()` and `createDataSet()` both of these simultaneously ,created data set in quicksight console is not able to import data as I want to make dashboard using these API for my data

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the data source is actually created and has the status: **"CREATION_SUCCESSFUL"**.

You can achieve this by using `DescribeDataSourceRequest` and getting from the result:

> describeDataSourceResult.getDataSource().getStatus()

The above SDK calls are for the **v.1 API** for Java.

Should be similar for **v.2 API** as well.